# MS SQL - performing a simple join

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am learning MS SQL from scratch and I am trying to create a join on my table but there's something wrong with my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Users.[User] JOIN Users.[User] as u ON (u.id = Users.[UserAddress].user);


Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'user'.
```

[image: table structure]

What's wrong :)?

Comment: Review: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx key words must be escaped; or better yet, not used.  I would also specify join type, inner, outer, Left, right, cross.  In my opinion it will aid in your understanding.  It's just like learning math, you don't start with the short cuts, you show all the work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`user` is a reserved word in SQL Server, so you need to enclose it in square braces.  The list of reserved words is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx).

I would recommend writing your query as:

```
SELECT *
FROM Users.[User] u JOIN
     Users.UserAddress ua
     ON u.id = ua.[user];
```

Note:  this also fixes the problem that you seem to want to join to `UserAddress` and not a self-join to `User`.

And some advice:

- Use table aliases for all your tables.  They make queries easier to read and write.
- The table aliases should be abbreviations for the tables.
- Avoid using reserved words for table and column names.
- Avoid square braces (unless you really need them); they make queries harder to write and to read.

In addition, I usually give my tables names in the plural (`Users`) with a primary key in the singular (`UserId`), and then always try to have foreign keys have the same name (`UserId` in both cases).

Comment: Thanks for the hints and quick response! :) It works but maangement studio underlines "Users.UserAddress" and "ua.[user]" in "(u.id = ua.[user])". 

First message is invalid object name and second: "the multi-part identifier 'ua.user' could not be bound". Why is that happening?

Comment: "the multi-part identifier 'ua.user' could not be bound" I've fixed that by clearing cache

Answer (score 0):

User is a keyword, so to access a column "user", you have to put it into square brackets:

```
SELECT * FROM Users.[User] JOIN Users.[User] as u ON (u.id = Users.[UserAddress].[user]);
```